# Covariance of transformation of discrete random variables

Tags: self-study, covariance, independence, bernoulli-distribution

I took a test earlier this year where I couldn't fully answer to one question. I wanted to post it here together with my reasoning to see if I can now get it.

Let $$X_1, X_2,X_3\stackrel{iid}{\sim}Ber(0.5)$$
And $$Y_1=2X_1-1;\;\;\;\; Y_2=2X_2-1;\;\;\; Z_1=Y_1*X_3;\;\;\; Z_2=Y_2*X_3$$

I was first asked to check if $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent, if $Y_1$ and $X_3$ are independent, and if $Y_2$ and $X_3$ are independent.

My reasoning here is that yes, $Y1$ and $Y2$ are independent since they are transformations of two distinct and themselves independent random variables. $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are also independent in regard to $X_3$ since they are just transformations of $X_1$ and $X_2$.

I was then asked to compute the expectation of $Z_1$ and $Z_2$. I figure that it could be solved like this: $$E(Z_1) = E(Y_1*X_3)\stackrel{indep.}{=}E(Y_1)*E(X_3)=0$$

The same goes for $Z_2$, as they have the same distribution.

What gave some troubles is when they asked me to compute the covariance between $Z_1$ and $Z_2$. In particular, my feeling is that they are **not** independent, but the covariance I computed has 0 as a result. Here's what I did, let me know if it makes sense:

Since the expected value of both $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ is 0, I just need to find $E(Z_1Z_2)$ to compute their covariance.

Now, since for each $Y$:
$$\begin{equation}
  p_Y(y) =
    \begin{cases}
      0.5 & \text{$y = -1$}\\
      0.5 & \text{$y = +1$}\\
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}
$$
I think it can be said that the PMF for both these random variables is $$
\begin{equation}
  p_Z(z) =
    \begin{cases}
      0.25 & \text{$z = -1$}\\
      0.5 & \text{$z = 0$}\\
      0.25 & \text{$z = +1$}
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}
$$

Now, for the new random variable $Z_1Z_2$:
\begin{equation}
  p_{(Z_1Z_2)}(z_1z_2) =
    \begin{cases}
      0.25 & \text{$z_1z_2 = -1$}\\
      0.5 & \text{$z_1z_2 = 0$}\\
      0.25 & \text{$z_1z_2 = +1$}
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}

Then,
$$Cov(Z_1, Z_2) = E(Z_1Z_2) = 0$$

Is everything correct? Is this one of those cases where, while the covariance is 0, the two random variables are actually not independent? Or are they independent after all and I just didn't see it? And also, is my reasoning too intricate and cumbersome? Maybe there's a faster way to solve a problem like this without computing all the PMFs as I did

Sorry for the lenghty question, and thanks to anyone who will answer!

Comment: You can quickly create a table with seven columns for all seven random variables you mention and eight rows for all possible (and equiprobable) outcomes.  That will tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: Thanks @whuber for your input. I may have misunderstood, but why do you mention eight outcomes? Aren't the possible outcomes between all of the seven variables just -1, 0 or +1?

Comment: $n$ binary variables have $2^n$ distinct outcomes.  Here, $n=3.$